# Is it dangerous/bad to call pthread_mutex_destroy with an uninitialized mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Example code:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return (0);
}
```

Is this a problem? I want to use a function that frees all allocated memory and destroys all mutexes in case of an error and returns, but i would sometimes call it when some of the mutexes are uninitialized. Would that be a problem?

Edit: Linux man says it's undefined behavior (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_destroy.3p.html)
Guess that means i probably shouldn't do it, but if it just affects the mutex i'm trying to destroy, and nothing else, should be fine if i don't use it afterwards, right?

Comment: Why would you need to destroy mutextes? It is dangerous. "Attempting  to  destroy  a locked  mutex,  or  a mutex that another thread is attempting to lock, or a mutex that is being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() call by another  thread,  results  in undefined behavior."

Comment: "The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the mutex argument to `pthread_mutex_destroy()` does not refer to an initialized mutex." - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_destroy.3p.html

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. of course no destroying while the mutex is in use. but you should destroy them before your program ends

Comment: @Laven Yes, but only the initialized ones.

Comment: If you know which mutexes are in use, how come you don't know which are initialised?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. i initialize multiple mutexes one after the other, and if one fails, i destroy all of them and return. it would be a lot of effort to keep track of which ones are already initialized and which arent

Comment: But isn't the exact same thing true about keeping track of which mutex is locked? If you hit a fatal error, just exit, don't try to destroy anything. Especially mutexes. See, an error to initialise a mutex can only be because of a bug in your program. Which means it is in an unknown and inconsistent state. It would be dangerous to do just about anything in such state, so do the absolute minimum: write a log message and exit.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. okay, thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: @n.m. "an error to initialise a mutex can only be because of a bug in your program"? What about the ENOMEM? Being able to destroy uninitialized mutexes is as handy as `free(NULL)`: it allows to avoid keeping track of which ones are already initialized and which aren't.

Comment: great, so i have completely different opinions on this lmao